# Windows Phone 7 best way to add picture to a listbox?

Tags: windows-phone-7

what is the best way to add picture to a listbox?

I have about 10 rss items, what is contains image urls (all picture is 300*300px)
About 300 picture

my BAD algorithm is the next:

```
1, download all xml file, and parse all with XDocument (i have then title and the image url)
2, using a datatemplate with an image and a textblock with Binding
3, lb.ItemsSource=alldatas;
```

This is very slow and laggy algorithm, what is the correct way to do this in WPF7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't sounds like you are doing anything particularly wrong. I am guessing the issue is that the 300 images are being loaded, which is causing the UI thread to be blocked. I would recommend reading about [David Anson's LowProfileImageLoader](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/09/02/keep-a-low-profile-lowprofileimageloader-helps-the-windows-phone-7-ui-thread-stay-responsive-by-loading-images-in-the-background.aspx), which reduces the amount of work being done on the UI thread.

Also, are you loading these elements into a ListBox? If so, I wrote about a more [lightweight approach here](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/04/a-fast-loading-windows-phone-7-navigationlist-control/).

Comment: I d like to use virtualizingstackpanel, but i dont know how to use virtualizingstackpanel from code. Can u help me?